# How to open the link in my app by the user's default app?

Tags: javascript, android, html, web-applications

I have an app for my website. I want Android to ask users in which App to open a link when they click on some special links on the site. Because sometimes I put links for live event in `*.ts` or `*.m3u8` extension but instead of opening the link by "default app", it starts downloading the file.

I think I need something like a code (`html`) to put with that link. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The most common problem in this category is having a phone number on a website which should open the "Dialer" app when a user clicks it. If I remember correctly, you need some javascript magic on the server side to detect the mobile client and then insert the correct HTML elements, such that the mobile browser detects the special link. Have a look here for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3656946/2102122

Comment: @potAito , Thank you so much.. I followed the answers in that topic but they didn't work. I want a code to put with the link on the page to do so, I want the link to be opened by mx player for example.